# Slow to unmap network drive letter

Tags: windows, performance, winapi, drive-letter

When I try to unmap network drive letter mappings using `WNetCancelConnection2` (or the depreciated `WNetCancelConnection`), the thread will block for about 10 seconds before the drive letter is actually unmapped if the file server is unavailable on the network. Is there a faster way to unmap this drive letter if the file server is not (and will not be) available?

Comment: `WNetCancelConnection2` is a generic function that loads the MPR dlls and queries them in the order set in "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\ProviderOrder" in order to have the correct provider remove the drive mapping. IIRC, they're queried sequentially, so a particular provider could be a bottleneck. If you know it's an SMB share, you can try [`NetUseDel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmuse/nf-lmuse-netusedel) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the third parameter `fForce` passed to [WNetCancelConnection2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetcancelconnection2a) to `true`. This should immediately terminate the connection. Please be aware that if there are open files or jobs on the connection you might loose data. So it might be a good idea to use a PING or some other means to establish whether the remote computer in online or not.